# How can I get all of my GMail directories to appear in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, gmail

In the left pane of Thunderbird, my GMail account e-mail address is listed and under it is "Inbox", "Drafts", "Sent" and "Deleted". When I access GMail via the web interface, there are other directories ("labels") such as "SMS". How can I get these to appear in Thunderbird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail), Gmail uses a special implementation of IMAP. In this implementation, Gmail labels become Thunderbird folders. When you apply a label to a message in Gmail, Thunderbird creates a folder with the same name as the label and stores the message in that folder. Similarly, if you move a message to a folder in Thunderbird, Gmail will create a label with the folder name and assign it to the message.

You should switch to IMAP if you're using POP3 and, in "Server Settings" for the GMail account, select "Advanced..." and then uncheck "Show only subscribed folders".

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your answer. My Thunderbird GMail server settings  have the server name set to imap.gmail.com (with the port set to 993 and the connection security set to SSL/TLS), but I don't see the "labels" appearing in Thunderbird as directories at all. Do you know what else I might need to do?

Comment: Wait, I found it. In "Server Settings" for the GMail account, select "Advanced..." and then uncheck "Show only subscribed folders". That seems to make the labels appear as directories in Thunderbird. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you're welcome. You found them yourself ;)

Comment: Well, I might not have seen that setting if you hadn't said to check that I was using IMAP. Thanks